# Draw circle without HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to draw a circle witout using HTML5 GRAPHICS.
This because I want to be able to edit the radius of the circle. And the circle needs to be selectable.

Is there a possibility to do this with javascript?

Comment: you could use a css border.

Comment: Just make an div with a border-radius: 100%

Comment: Thanks for the advise Daniel. Seems like the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Circle</title>
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
  div.circle {
    border: 3px solid green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
  }
</style>

<div class=circle></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your paradigms don't make sense to me, but you can draw a circle easily through something like this:

```
<div style="display:inline-block; 
        background:#f00; 
        width:250px; 
        height:250px; 
        border-radius:125px"></div>
```

Just make sure your border radius is at least half of your width/height.

Comment: "I want to edit the size of it" is a paradigm that doesn't make sense.  You can 'edit' the size of a canvas block, an SVG block, an HTML element, an image, or a background-image.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No idea what is wrong with my paradigms.

Comment: But once you draw a circle on a canvas, you can't change the radius afterwards

Comment: Wholly untrue.  You can always redraw it with a different radius.  That's the point of canvas: to be able to draw into and redraw when necessary

Comment: Well I didn't find a way to redraw a circle without clearing all elements on the canvas.

Comment: My circle also needs to be selectable.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the level of browser support you need you could use inline svg.

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: this way is not supported by all browsers and is a part of html5 graphics which I want to avoid